# Kafka Consumer Retry in Manual Commit

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Kafka manual commit property. But for my use case, I didn't manually commit the message purposely. I want to know after how much time Kafka will consume/poll that uncommitted message again.

Additionally Is there a way that I can set a retry to poll message after sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The record will not be resubmitted until you restart the consumer.

You can throw an exception and the default error handler will perform a seek so the record will be redelivered on the next poll.

Or, you can seek the partition(s) yourself by making your listener extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek